# jQuery sorting table columns

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I am trying to sort a Table with jQuery. In my table there are 2 columns I need to sort with and it has to hide the row if it is sorted.

My table looks something like this when created:

```
<table id="vermogen_gewicht" class="table table-hover vermogen_gewicht">
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="uitvoering_1 ">
        <td class="radiobutton">
        <td id="gewicht" class="gewicht">2000</td>
        <td id="type" class="type">L1H1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is everything i use to sort with jQuery. The jquery I use is this :

```
var criteria;
$('#filtertype').change(function(){
    var criteria = $(this).val();
    if(criteria == 'ALL'){
        $('.vermogen_gewicht tr').show();
        return;
    }
    $('.type').each(function(i,option){
        if($(this).html() == criteria){
            $(this).parent().show();
        }else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

What this does is that I select an option in a `<select>` element. Which then hides the elements that don't have the same value as the selected option. This works as expected but after I sorted based on the "type" I now want to sort based on the "gewicht"; I use this code to do so:

```
$('#filtertype1').change(function(){
    var criteria1 = $(this).val();
    if(criteria1 == 'ALL'){
        $('.vermogen_gewicht tr').show();
        return;
    }
    $('.gewicht').each(function(i,option){
        if($(this).html() == criteria1 && $('.type').html() == criteria){
            $(this).parent().show();
        }else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

But what this is not working, for example I select type 1, it shows every row tht contains type 1 and it hides the others. Then when I select 2000 on the element "gewicht" it should show everything with type 1 and gewicht 2000 but now it just hides everything when I do this.

Even when i change this: 
 `if($(this).html() == criteria1 && $('.type').html() == criteria){` 
to this
`if($(this).html() == criteria1 {`
It will work correctly, If i select type = 1 gewicht = 2000 then it will show that correctly and hide the other rows but when I change the "gewicht" to 2100 it will also show the type 2 so it overwrites the first sort. That may not happen. How do i fix this?

Comment: "d it has to hide the row if it is sorted." - so once you sort you hide all the rows?  Makes no sense, please clarify

Comment: Show some table markup with some example pre and post sort - showing a one row table makes it less clear

Comment: td with class "radiobutton" has no content or closing tag

Comment: I think you are speaking about filtering (hiding those rows that not match a criteria) rather than sorting (arrange rows in a different order but keeping them all visible)